# Calling Python Function as UDF from TEIID

Tags: java, wildfly, jython, teiid

If I have series of functions in python that I want to call from TEIID VDB as UDF. Is that possible without having to convert it to native Java based code ? Can this be done using Jython ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know Jython, but UDF invokes a Java-based method, how you wrap under that class with other languages does not matter. So as long as you can call your Python function from this wrapper it should work.